# I need to make a redstone clock that has the same timings as this one but with no observers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

[image]

I am making a redstone contraption that needs perfect timing and the server I am on doesn't have observers, it also needs to be toggleable.

Comment: Generally, we dislike it when users delete and [repost their question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/330134/i-need-to-do-this-but-without-obsevers).  Show us *something* that you've tried.  We like effort, and we're not seeing any here.

Comment: this is a different question the last one I figured out myself, I found a Youtube vid on vertical redstone, this is a redstone clock that needs precise timing or the contraption will brake.

Comment: you can see what I did in the top right corner of the screenshot, that powered torch is part of a torch tower.

Comment: When you post the same question, with just a different picture, it doesn't seem like a different question. Give us more detail and what you've tried. Arqade does not respond well to being treated like a service desk.

Comment: I had looked into redstone clocks and I tried a hoper clock and I couldn't get the timings right

Answer (score 0):

to power it, place a lever on top of a birch block. Now turn it on and off very fast. That should work :)
[image: set 3 repeated on 4 ticks and 1 repeater on 1 tick]

Comment: I should have originally specified that it needs to be toggled.

Comment: "turn it on and off very fast" does not sound like a step toward creating a clock with perfect timing.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this clock will fit the timings well enough to work! Simply flick the lever on or off to toggle the clock.

[image: here's the clock for you]